# Given an object of an unknown type, How would you check to see if it responds to a given message/selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Given an object of an unknown type, How would you check to see if it responds to a given message/selector?

Comment: Are these interview questions? Homework?

Comment: I see that someone is trying to ask you interview questions lifted word-for-word from D Carney's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087528/objective-c-iphone-developer-interview-questions/4088140#4088140 .

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([yourObject respondsToSelector:@selector(selectorMethod)])
{
//Do something

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
[theObject respondsToSelector:@selector(theSelector)];
```